# How to implement an algorithm with pointers and memory allocation in Java

Tags: java, pointers, migration, malloc, double-pointer

I have an algorithm in C++ and I need to implement something similar in Java. I'm having trouble with memory allocation. How can I migrate the following snippet for example, from C++ to Java?

```
size_x = 3; size_y = 6; 
double **Data, *pDataData;
Data = (double **)malloc(size_x*sizeof(double *)+size_x*size_y*sizeof(double));
for (i = 0, pDataData = (double *)(Data+size_x); i < size_x; i++, pDataData += size_y)
Data[i]=pDataData;
```

I know that for a simple malloc like:
   char *x = (char *) malloc(256);
In Java, I would say:
   ByteBuffer x = ByteBuffer.allocate(250);

For anything more complicated, I get confused.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if Java has those capabilities...even if it did, it's sort of like asking a can opener to slice a potato...you just shouldn't do it, and you risk serious injury to self and other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It is neither necessary nor desirable to do such a thing in Java or in C++. Since the invention of classes, when you need a complex structure, you should create a class, not allocate an amorphous blob of memory and then put things in that memory that are retrieved by an offset rather than a name.

So it looks like you're trying to allocate an array of size_x of pointers to doubles, and then a two-dimensional array of size size_x by size_y of doubles, with the pointers pointing to successive rows in the table? Sorry if I'm not understanding what you're trying to do. This is exactly why the Java way is, in my humble opinion, superior: Complex structures are not that hard to figure out.

In Java, there would be no need to have the pointers to the rows. So in Java this would just turn into:

```
public class MyDataData
{
  double[][] table;

  public MyDataData(int size_x, int size_y)
  {
    table=new double[size_x][size_y];
  }
}
```

To invoke it you'd just write

```
MyDataData whatever=new MyDataData(3,6);
```

And that would be about it. If you need a reference to a row, you'd just get table[x].

Don't try to simulate malloc in Java. That's not how it's done. Just define the class you need and use "new" to make one, and Java will worry about allocating the memory for you.

Answer (score 5):

That's a 2 dimensional array.

```
double Data[][] = new double[size_x][size_y];
```

Comment: This is just funny.  This question really illustrates the difference (at times) between the complexity of Java and the complexity of C++...

Comment: @Chris Thompson: No funny is that people think that the above is C++ code. C++ code would look pretty much identical to the Java code. You can write horrible code in pretty much any language. The above is just C code and not especially well written one at that - actually seems a bit buggy for the allocation)

Comment: @Voo: Someone once said, "A sufficiently skilled programmer can write a FORTRAN program in any language." Apparently you can write a C program in any language, too. I'm presently working on a Java application where for every class, the original programmer created an interface. Even when there is only one class that implements it, ano reason to believe there'll ever be another, and all references are in the same package. It hit me that this guy was originally a C programmer. I bet he thought, "So how do I create a .h file in Java? Oh, here it is, in Java they call it an interface ..."